# Expressions for multipole moments

Tags: electrostatics, multipole-expansion

I am trying to understand the multipole expansion, though I don't have a background in EM. Wikipedia gives the [expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion#Expansion_in_Cartesian_coordinates) for the Coulomb potential for dipole and quadrupole moments in terms of $1/r^{3}$ and $1/r^{5}$, whereas Griffiths gives the corresponding potentials as $1/r^{2}$ and $1/r^{3}$. Why the apparent discrepancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sources claim dipole and quadrupole moments have potentials that go as $1/r^2$ and $1/r^3$, respectively. For example, the Wikipedia article states that the dipole potential is given by
$$v_a(\mathbf{R}) = -\frac{R_a}{R^3} \sim \frac{R}{R^3} = \frac{1}{R^2},$$
and similarly for the quadrupole. It is common (e.g. in Griffiths), especially when writing out electric and magnetic fields, to use unit vectors instead of their non-normalized counterparts. This means cancelling out by a quantity of length-dimension one in both the denominator and numerator. For example, the dipole electric field goes as
$$\mathbf{E} \sim \frac{3\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}}-\mathbf{p}}{r^3} \sim \frac{3\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{p}||{\mathbf{r}||}}{r^4}.$$
The Wikipedia article uses the latter convention.

Comment: +1 Thank you, that was exceptionally clear. Just one more thing -- would you mind elaborating on what $R_{a}$ is? As far as I can tell, the article doesn't mention what it is.

Comment: $R_a$ here is the $a$th component of the displacement vector $\mathbf{R}$. For example, we could have $R_1 = x$, $R_2 = y$, and $R_3 = z$.